# Store complex value type in a .dat file (python)

Tags: python

I have a series of complex eigenvectors which I would like to store in the following format:

(real part of eigvector 1, imag. part of eigvector1, real part of eigvector 2, imag. part of eigvector 2,...)

Then the first two columns correspond to the real and imaginary part respectively of the first eigenvector and so on.

By doing: 
`np.savetxt('Eigenvectors.dat',myeigenvectors)` I get the following format:

```
(-6.200989494250344625e-02+0.000000000000000000e+00j)
```

for every element which is not suitable for reading in other languages such as c++.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Adam's answer, but a bit cleaner code, regardless of whether it's a numpy array or a standard python list:

```
complex_split = [(v.real,v.imag) for v in clist]
```

If you're worried about runtime for this part of the code then there may be advantages to using `clist.real` and `clist.imag` and then using `zip`, but I'm not sure about relative run times.

Comment: Thank you Joel but I don't know how to turn your answers into a solution. I have a 864x864 np.array. Each column is an eigenvector. By doing what you guys say I come up with a list of 864 elements in which each element is a tuple of np.arrays. What I need is an 864x 1728 np.array and then save it into a .dat file

Comment: can you describe exactly what you want your output to look like?

Comment: In columns: (real part of eigvector 1, imag. part of eigvector1, real part of eigvector 2, imag. part of eigvector 2,...) If the initial array is 864x864 then what I need is a 864x 1728 np.array

Answer (score 0):

If these are in a complex numpy array:

```
real = carray.real
image = carray.imag
```

If they are stored in a list of complex values:

```
real = [v.real for v in clist]
image = [v.imag for v in clist]
```

Then just output the combined list:

```
complex_split = zip(real, image)
```

That should produce a list of itemized real and imag parts like:

```
( (r1, i1), (r2, i2) ) etc...
```

Comment: you should change `carray.image` to `carray.imag`

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this doesn't store anything into a .dat file in the desired format

Comment: Couldn't you just open a file the standard way and write the items in a for loop?  `with open('out.dat' as o): o.write_lines(complex_split)` instead of numpy savetxt?